# How to produce a running sequence in Oracle based on report column values

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex, oracle12c

I have the following sample Oracle APEX report by where the Origin ID and Origin Name are retrieved from the `origin_tab(id,origin_id,origin_name)`

Based on these two column values, I need to generate the Temporary Origin ID value on the fly as part of the selection retrieval from the `origin_tab`.

The rule behind this is - where the Origin Name is the same against the Origin ID, take the Origin ID value before the dash and append a 3-digit sequence for each Orgin ID as per example below.

Since the origin name (AAA) is the same for the first two records, '`001`' is appended to the origin id `1111`. The same for BBB, '002' is appended to those three records and so forth.

Please note that the `Temporary Origin ID` here is a string.

```
Origin ID         Origin Name        Temporary Origin ID
----------------- ------------------ --------------------
1111-1            AAA                1111001
1111-2            AAA                1111001
1111-3            BBB                1111002
1111-4            BBB                1111002
1111-5            BBB                1111002
1111-6            CCC                1111003
1111-7            DDD                1111004
1111-8            DDD                1111004
```

What approach should I take in my query to achieve the above result, for the Temporary Origin ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dense_rank()`:

```
select t.*,
       (substr(origin_id, 1, 4) ||
        lpad(dense_rank() over (order by origin_name), 4, '0')
       ) as temp_origin_id
from t;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=d4801817fe8cbcc17531d5320d73be85) is a db<>fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Make a flag column and put there `1` every time when name changes. You can detect this using `lag()` or subquery. Then concatenate analytical sum of flag column to `1111`.

```
select Origin_ID, Origin_Name, 
       '1111'||lpad(sum(flag) over (order by origin_id), 3, '0') Temp_Origin_ID
  from (
    select t.*, 
           case lag(origin_name) over (order by origin_id) when origin_name then 0 else 1 end flag 
      from t)
  order by Origin_ID
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e48784800a0aaaf53872bfad1680f408)</sup>**